# ssl certificate installation on tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, godaddy

I am trying to create a new certificate for my **scala play framework** on **ubuntu** but I cannot import my key with keytool. I haven't been able to figure out what is causing it so I thought I'd see here if anyone recognizes my problem.

I first create my private key using

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

Then I generate my CSR

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file my-csr-file.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

copy and paste the generated CSR into godady

select the tomcat server on godaddy and i received godaddy new certification.i get 3 files:

```
28042ad1aadd20.crt
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
gdig2.crt
```

Installing Root and Intermediate Certificates

```
wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/valicert_class2_root.crt –no-check-certificate
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file valicert_class2_root.crt

wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_cross_intermediate.crt –no-check-certificate
keytool -import -alias cross -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_cross_intermediate.crt
```

Second intermediate (gd_intermediate.crt):

```
wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_intermediate.crt –no-check-certificate
keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_intermediate.crt
```

Installing SSL Certificate

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file my-csr-file.csr
```

Here I receive the following error

```
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 49)
```

Anyone recognize the problem?
or any other way to install godaddy ssl certificate for tomcat server using ubuntu

Comment: This can be due to several different things, namely: absent JCE, parsing errors in your cert (if ASCII, remove unneeded headers before `---BEGIN CERT---`). Try `keytool -printcert` on your cert to see a full error report.

Comment: `gd_cross_intermediate.crt` and `gd_intermediate.crt` *used to be* correct, but in 2014 all major CAs including GoDaddy **changed to SHA-256** for certs instead of SHA-1; for GoDaddy **these are called "G2"**. `gdig2.crt` is the new G2 intermediate for clients that have the GoDaddy G2 root, which now (in 2015) most do. `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` is the new cross-chain if clients have only old GoDaddy root; either split out the first two certs and add them separately, or concatentate at least those two after your leaf cert and import that chain against the privatekey alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSR is used to generate a CRT, you need to go to godaddy and paste the CSR value from this keystore, this will generate the CRT - which you then import. At present, you are trying to add the CSR not a CRT.

Comment: OP did paste the CSR to Godaddy and "get 3 files" of which `28042ad1aadd20.crt` is obviously the cert. He just needs to *use* that file -- and with the correct chain, see above.